# Delete Headers and Trailer from File C# File.ReadAllLines

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a file and produce a new file without lines that contain "HEADER" or "TRAILER".  Below is my code.  When I put a breakpoint at text[i].Remove(i), it appears to execute that code but the text variable never removes the line.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        var text = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string line in text)
        {
            if (line.Substring(0, 20).Contains("HEADER") || line.Substring(0, 20).Contains("TRAILER"))
            {
                text[i].Remove(i);
            }
            else
            { 
            i++;
            }
        }
        string newFN = fileName + "b";
        File.WriteAllLines(newFN, text);
```

Comment: You can't modify an enumerable while enumerating it.

Comment: Also `text[i].Remove(i)` most likely doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Also the way you call `Remove` you'd be calling it on (the characters of) a line itself. So you're telling the line to remove characters beginning at index `i` within `text[i]` (a line) . But because strings are immutable you are returning a new string and doing nothing with it. In addition to what the other comments and answers say about removing from an enumerable, you're mixing two different types of `Remove`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx Also you should look at `string.StartsWith` since your lines may not be 20 chars long and `Substring` could fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.WriteAllLines(filename + "b", File.ReadAllLines(filename)
    .Select(l => l.Substring(0, 20))
    .Where(s => !s.Contains("HEADER") && !s.Contains("TRAILER")));
```

You can read in all the lines, select the first 20 character of each line, and then use `Where` to exclude all lines in which the first 20 characters contain HEADER or TRAILER and then write those resulting lines to file.

Comment: Note that OP's code is `line.Substring(0, 20).Contains("HEADER")` which is very different than `line.StartsWith("HEADER")`. Their code allows header to be found anywhere within the first 20 characters but your code only allows it to exist starting at position 0.

Comment: Excellent answer but I need the whole line not just the first 20 Characters.  Do I just do .Select (l => l)  and s.Substring(0,20).Contains

Comment: So you want to check if HEADER or TRAILER appear anywhere in the line?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change enumerable from within an enumerator. Create new writable collection and insert only those lines matching your predicate or use LINQ for creating new enumerable that has your criteria already applied and then map it to an array or a list or whatever collection you need.

Answer (score 1):

`ReadAllLines` returns an string array. You can use LINQ to select to new output from `text`

```
var text = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Select(i => {line.Contains("HEADER")? "": line});

File.WriteAllLines(newFN, text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ReadAllLines` as it allows you to enumerate while it is still reading more lines of the file. This way you do not have to read the entire file into memory before you start writing out the new file. You could then simplify your code down to this one line:

```
File.WriteAllLines(fileName + "b", File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(line => !line.Contains("HEADER") | !line.Contains("TRAILER")));
```

This will cause it to leave out the HEADER and TRAILER lines when writing the new file.

Also, to more completely answer your question [String.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx) will remove all characters from the index to the end of the string and return you a new string. Strings in .Net are immutable and so it will not modify the current string, just give you back a new string.  Also, when you call `Substring` in your comparisons, those methods are creating new string instances just for you to check if a string is contained within that stretch of characters.  It would be better to just call `Contains` on the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(fileName);
var filtered = lines.Where(line => !line.Contains("HEADER") && !line.Contains("TRAILER")));
File.WriteAllLines(filename + "b", filtered);     // or filename.Replace(".txt", "b.txt") ?
```

`.Substring(0, 20)` allocates memory for a new string and will fail for lines that have less than 20 characters, so in most cases just `.Contains` will be faster. Or, you can use `.IndexOf` instead:

```
line.IndexOf("HEADER", 0, 20, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0
```

---

I am guessing that RegEx might be a bit faster by avoiding some of the extra memory allocations:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
string[] parts = Regex.Split(text, @"\n?\r?.*(HEAD|TRAIL)ER.*\n?\r?");
File.WriteAllLines(filename + "b", parts);
```